# Overriding create method in Django RestFramework to POST data

Tags: python, json, django, datetime

I'm currently using Django RestFramework to create APIs that use both GET and POST to retrieve/insert data within my Django application.  I currently have a database model called TransactionDateTime that has a field called start_dt (see below), which takes DateTimeField.  The challenge is that I'm passing a string in my json POST data structure (see below) and I need to override the create method in order to loop through the JSON structure to convert the string to the appropriate datetime structure. I know the logic to be used to successfully convert string to datetime, because I was able to perform it in the Django shell (see below), but I don't know how to override the create method and write the appropriate code within the create method to make this happen.  Please assist.  Below is a copy of my view that is successfully returning JSON data structure via GET, with a BIG question within the create method

TransactionDateTime model from models.py

```
class TransactionDateTime(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_dt = models.DateTimeField('start_dateTime')
    end_dt = models.DateTimeField('end_dateTime', blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start_dt)
```

Data Structure to be used on POST

```
[
  {
    "start_dt": "2015-01-28 03:00:00"
  },

  {
    "start_dt": "2015-01-28 05:30:00"
  }
]
```

Logic to convert string to datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.strptime('2015-01-28 05:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Django Mixin and View

```
class DateTimeMixin(object):
    serializer_class = SimpleSerializer4
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)


class DateTimeViewSet(DateTimeMixin, generics.BulkModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):

        num = self.kwargs['dt_rm']
        num2 = self.kwargs['id']

        r1 = Room.objects.get(id = num)

        s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=num2)
        u= self.request.user.pk
        usr = User.objects.get(pk=u)

        if(s1.user.username == usr.username):
            queryset = r1.transactiondatetime_set.all()
            return queryset
        else: raise Http404("User does not exist")



    def get_serializer_context(self):

        num = self.kwargs['id']
        s1 = Schedule.objects.get(pk=num)
        var = s1.user.username
        context = super(DateTimeViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        return {'request' : var}


    def created(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ???
```

Comment: Have you tried to change [`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting) to include yours?

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to go about it is not to write your own custom create method, but rather to teach your serializer how to accept the date format you use, e.g.

```
class SimpleSerializer4(something_here):
    ...
    start_dt = serializers.DateTimeField(format=api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT, input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])
    ...
```

Then later all you have to do is to add `CreateModelMixin` to you `ViewSet` and it should work, e.g.

```
from rest_framework.mixins import CreateModelMixin
...
class DateTimeViewSet(DateTimeMixin, CreateModelMixin, generics.BulkModelViewSet):
...
```

Docs on DateTimeField [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield%20here)

Docs on extending view sets [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#custom-viewset-base-classes)

And I found it often very helpful to look how things are done in the rest_framework itself, so [here is the link to the source on GitHub](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework)